# Angular how load an array of data to multi select menu

Tags: angular

I have provided the structure of the data from the link below. I have no problem loading an data to multi select when in creating records which is the n *ngFor="let data of FilteredYear" value="{{ data }}">{{ data }} now the issue is when it comes to editing and loading the records to multi select.I wanted to load the array of data for example "year" to the form as comma delimited and when I select or add new data those select should already bec checked on the multi select and no value should be selected twice. Any idea or mistake with my code ?. I have no problem loading the data into the mat form field name the problem is on the multi select year. Btw data is loaded on  this.frm = this.fb.group  ...

## HTML

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" class="name-input">
            <mat-hint align="end"></mat-hint>
            <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="frm.controls.Stock.invalid"></mat-error> -->
        </mat-form-field>



        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
            <mat-select  multiple formControlName="year">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let data of FilteredYear" value="{{ data }}">{{ data }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

## Data Structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wGFa.jpg

## If on edit data should be display so multi select as shown in the image below , the data came from  let data = this.data.data; when I have provided the data structure above,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKgF0.jpg

## form component ts

initializeForm() {

```
if (this.data.action == 'edit') {

    let data = this.data.data;

    this.frm = this.fb.group({
        summer_sale_value: new FormControl(data.summer_sale_value, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
        name: new FormControl(data.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
        email: new FormControl(data.email, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
        body: new FormControl(data.data[0].body, null),
        make: new FormControl(data.data[0].make, null),
        year: new FormControl(data.data[0].year, null),
        model: new FormControl(data.data[0].model, null),
        _id: new FormControl(data._id),

    });

} else {



    this.frm = new FormGroup({
        summer_sale_value: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
        name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
        body: new FormControl(null),
        make: new FormControl(null),
        year: new FormControl(null),
        model: new FormControl(null),


    });
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this already thanks.

Comment: please post the solution or close the question